# How to group rows and estimate the difference between maximum and minimum values?

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have the following pandas DataFrame `df`:

```
id  date_time
0   2017-12-04 03:59:44
0   2017-12-04 04:01:44
1   2017-12-04 04:04:44
1   2017-12-04 04:08:44
1   2017-12-04 04:08:44
```

If I print the `type` of each particular `date_time` row, then I get the type `<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'>`.

I need to group rows by `id` and estimate the difference (in seconds) between maximum and minimum `date_time` values.

I tried to run this code:

```
s = df.groupby('id').date_time.transform(lambda x: (x.max()-x.min()).seconds)
```

But `s` gives the following output format (the values might not coincide with the above example, but the format coincides):

```
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000
1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000120
```

As it can be seen, the values are not seconds, but are date and time values. How can I get numerical values that are seconds?

I tried to use `df["date_time"] = df["date_time"].apply(lambda x: x.to_pydatetime())`, but it did not help.

Comment: The following works for me: `df.groupby('id')['date_time'].transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min()).dt.seconds`. Also your own method gives correct output as well.

Comment: What is the output of: `type(df['date_time'].iat[0])` & `print(pd.__version__)`?

Comment: @Erfan: Thanks, but I should be able to later run `df[s>200]` in order to retrieve rows. If I run `apply`, the output is different from `transform`.

Comment: @Erfan: Pandas version is `0.19.2`. The output of `type` is 
`pandas.tslib.Timestamp`.

Comment: try appending `(x.max()-x.min()).astype('timedelta64[s]')`